# How to prevent imports outside of the rootDir?

Tags: typescript

We have a structure monorepo structure that could be summarized as:

```
/apps/
└── /foo
/packages/
└── /bar
```

`/apps/foo/tsconfig.json` has `rootDir` set to `.`.

However, `/apps/foo/src/index.ts` is able to import types from `/packages/bar` using relative path, such as:

```
import { type Bar } from '../../../packages/bar/types';
```

How do I prevent imports outside of the `rootDir`?

The entire `tsconfig.json` is:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "declaration": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "*"
      ]
    },
    "rootDir": ".",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "sourceRoot": "/",
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2018",
    "useUnknownInCatchVariables": false
  },
  "include": [
    "vitest.config.ts",
    "src/generated",
    "./src/.eslintrc.js",
    "src",
    "test",
    "testV2",
    "types",
    "./bin/**.js",
    "./codegen/**.js",
    "./test/.eslintrc.js"
  ]
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is TypeScript's job. Maybe there's a linter that does this.

Comment: This is what you need
https://github.com/azz/eslint-plugin-monorepo